# where does ES store data

Tags: elasticsearch

Similar questions were asked before suggestion to hit:

`http://127.0.0.1:9200/_nodes/stats/fs?prett`y

This shows:

```
{
  "_nodes" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "nodes" : {
    "-MS6L0okT7SwuQQzp64F0Q" : {
      "timestamp" : 1568228571281,
      "name" : "Bladiblah",
      "transport_address" : "127.0.0.1:9300",
      "host" : "127.0.0.1",
      "ip" : "127.0.0.1:9300",
      "roles" : [
        "ingest",
        "master",
        "data"
      ],
      "attributes" : {
        "ml.machine_memory" : "274841600000",
        "xpack.installed" : "true",
        "ml.max_open_jobs" : "20"
      },
      "fs" : {
        "timestamp" : 1568228571281,
        "total" : {
          "total_in_bytes" : 400052711424,
          "free_in_bytes" : 317666811904,
          "available_in_bytes" : 317666811904
        },
        "least_usage_estimate" : {
          "path" : "C:\\elasticsearch-7.3.1\\data\\nodes\\0",
          "total_in_bytes" : 400052711424,
          "available_in_bytes" : 317666963456,
          "used_disk_percent" : 20.593723180814195
        },
        "most_usage_estimate" : {
          "path" : "C:\\elasticsearch-7.3.1\\data\\nodes\\0",
          "total_in_bytes" : 400052711424,
          "available_in_bytes" : 317666963456,
          "used_disk_percent" : 20.593723180814195
        },
        "data" : [
          {
            "path" : "C:\\elasticsearch-7.3.1\\data\\nodes\\0",
            "mount" : "(C:)",
            "type" : "NTFS",
            "total_in_bytes" : 400052711424,
            "free_in_bytes" : 317666811904,
            "available_in_bytes" : 317666811904
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This shows that quite a bit of memory is used. However, when I go to:

```
C:\elasticsearch-7.3.1\data\nodes\0
```

and go to properties the used memory is only a few kilobytes. Am I missing something?

Comment: do you have indices? looks like you don't

Comment: that's how big is your windows disk and how much space is available

Comment: Try `http://127.0.0.1:9200/_all/_stats?pretty` instead that will give you the size taken by all your indices.